# Pass the text box value in form action

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form method="post" action="http://xyz.com/?value="+textBox1.val+"&area="+textBox2.val>
    <input type="text" name="textBox1"></input>
    <input type="text" name="textBox2"></input>
    <div>Click here</div>
</form>
```

On Clicking the div.text "Click Here", form action must be performed.

The textBox values should get populated in the url.

Comment: Even when it is empty?

Comment: How are u setting the textbox values in javascript var, also u jst need to write url in action, values will be submitted automatically

Comment: I mean after filling the text box in html

Comment: basically i need to give the email address to the textbox and that email address should be passed to the action url

Comment: when you submit the form, those values will get passed. You don't need to from `action` param again.

Comment: action url from form already have access to POST or GET variables after submit (depend on method property).Why you want to do it in action url? you can use basic php form to submit or ajax if you dont want that page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

use forms properties instead of javascript or jquery

```
 <form method="get" action="http://xyz.com/">
   <input type="text" name="value" />
   <input type="text" name="area" />
   <input type="submit" value="Click here"/>
</form>
```

Comment: in the action url, i need to populate the value.val()
wanna some solution regarding that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are missing `id` or `class` attributes, I'll answer based on your code. It is highly recommended that you use classes instead.

```
$('form div').on( 'click', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax( {
        url: "http://xyz.com/",
        type: 'get',
        data: {value: $('input[name=textBox1]').val(), area: $('input[name=textBox2]').val()},
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The inputs in the HTML are named 'textarea1' and 'textarea2', not 'value' and 'area'.

Answer (score 0):

Your form method is post ..  so no need to append textBox1 to url.If appendinmg to url is necessary ..  use get method(form method="get").

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="http://xyz.com">
    <input type="text" name="textBox1"></input>
    <input type="text" name="textBox2"></input>
    <div onclick="document.myForm.submit()">Click here</div>
</form>
```